# Eigenstates of a Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

For a particle with a spin of 1/2, which was exposed to both magnetic fields

$B_{0}=B_{z}e_z$
 and 
$B_1=B_xe_x$

I already found the eigenvalues of its Hamiltonian which is given by 
\begin{equation}
H = -\gamma (B_0+B_1)\cdot S=-\dfrac{\gamma \hbar}{2} (B_x\sigma_x+B_z\sigma_z)
\end{equation}

and they were

$E_{\pm}=\mp \dfrac{\gamma \hbar}{2} \sqrt{B_z^2+B_x^2}$

can anyone guide me to find its eigenstates?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and eigenvector $\mathbf{u}$.

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{u} \; = \; \lambda \mathbf{u}
\end{align}
Since your question is for $2 \times 2$ matrix, we explicitly write it as
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{A}}
\;
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}\\
u_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
}_{\mathbf{u}}
\; = \;
\lambda
\;
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}\\
u_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
}_{\mathbf{u}}
\end{align}
For **each** eigenvalue $\lambda$, we are ready to solve $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$
\begin{align}
au_{1} + bu_{2} = \lambda u_{1} \tag{1}\\
cu_{1} + du_{2} = \lambda u_{1} \tag{2}
\end{align}
Notice that Eq. (1) and (2) are *linearly dependent* in this case. So you actually need one equation only (say Eq. (1)). Thus, we have
\begin{align}
b u_{2} \; = \; (\lambda - a)u_{1}
\end{align}
Now, it seems that we don't have unique solution. Yes, remember that eigenvector is in general not unique since the vector norm is not fixed.

We pick $u_{1} = 1$, then we have $u_{2} = (\lambda - a)/b$. Since we are talking a quantum state, we have to normalize the eigenvector by $\sqrt{u_{1}^{2} + u_{2}^{2}}$.